# Tricky string replace with 2 strings combined using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to do something sort of tricky with 2 strings and am not sure how to go about it. It's sort of a backwards match/replace. I want to replace anything outside of the match within the string. The tricky part is that the part of the string that I want to replace is parts of another string, based on the position of where the match was found.

I have the following variables to work with:

```
var keepMe = '#INDEX_NESTED#';
var stringFind = 'test[#INDEX#][nested][#INDEX_NESTED#][dcap]';
var stringReplace = 'test[0][nested][0][dcap]';
```

The goal is to get the following output:

```
test[0][nested][#INDEX_NESTED#][dcap]
```

Please assume that everything is dynamic so nothing can be hard coded.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: The simple way is `(all before)(what you want to match)(all after)` and you have the three pieces.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code how to do so? I'm still not following..

Comment: Yeah I just figured somebody would have some clever way to do so using substring with positions or something like that. I may take a step back and see if I can do something different in the core script. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to achieve this. One approach would be to split both of the strings at each `[` character using the expression `/(?=\[)/`. This is just a positive lookahead that will match behind each `[` character. Then you can map a new array while comparing the elements in each array by their index.

```
var replaceArray = stringReplace.split(/(?=\[)/);
var result = stringFind.split(/(?=\[)/).map(function (value, index) {
  return value.indexOf(keepMe) > -1 ? value : replaceArray[index];
}).join('');
```

Full example:

```js
var keepMe = '#INDEX_NESTED#';
var stringFind = 'test[#INDEX#][nested][#INDEX_NESTED#][dcap]';
var stringReplace = 'test[0][nested][0][dcap]';

var replaceArray = stringReplace.split(/(?=\[)/);
var result = stringFind.split(/(?=\[)/).map(function (value, index) {
  return value.indexOf(keepMe) > -1 ? value : replaceArray[index];
}).join('');

document.body.textContent = result;
```